# Differential equation with integral that is hard to compute

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Task and my attempt to solve it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JitKO.jpg)

$$xy'=\sqrt{2x^2+y^2}-y$$

I have tried substitution like $y=z·x$ but finally got very difficult integral 
$$ \int \frac{dz}{\sqrt{2+z^2}-2z}=\int\frac{dx}{x}$$
at the left side.

Maybe i have to do something different to avoid difficult computation?

Please explain me how to solve it.

Comment: Try $z=\sqrt2\sinh u$.

Comment: And then $v=e^{2u}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Multiply by $\frac{\sqrt{2+z^2}+2z}{\sqrt{2+z^2}+2z}$:
   $$
   \int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{2+z^2}-2z}=\int\frac{\sqrt{2+z^2}+2z}{(2+z^2)-4z^2}\,dz=\int\frac{\sqrt{2+z^2}}{2-3z^2}\,dz+\int\frac{2z}{2-3z^2}\,dz.
   $$
   The second integral is simple.
2. In the first integral do the change of variables $t=z+\sqrt{z^2+2}$:
   $$
   \int\frac{\sqrt{2+z^2}}{2-3z^2}\,dz=\int\frac{(t^2+2)^2}{t(-3t^4+20t^2-12)}\,dt.
   $$
3. Another change of variables $u=t^2$ gives
   $$
   \int\frac{(t^2+2)^2}{t(-3t^4+20t^2-12)}\,dt=\int\frac{\frac12(u+2)^2}{u(-3u^2+20u-12)}\,du=\frac12\int\frac{(u+2)^2}{u(u-6)(2-3u)}\,du
   $$
   which can be calculated by partial fractions.

However, I wouldn't wish finding $y(x)$ [explicitly](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+xy%27%3Dsqrt(2x%5E2%2By%5E2)-y) after all that.